# Extracting entity name from FetchXml columns in Dynamics 365 Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fetchxml, dynamics-365

I'm trying to write a SQL query that shows all Advanced Find views owned by a specific user in Dynamics 365 b8.2 (on-prem).

This is pretty straight-forward in terms of getting the view name, and User from the UserQuery view, but the entity related to that view is only stored as part of the FetchXML, so I need to extract that.

Can I use XPath on Fetch XML?  Any help would be awesome!  Two examples of the FetchXML are as follows (the entity is Account):

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0" distinct="false" output-format="xml-platform">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="address2_city" />
    <attribute name="parentaccountid" />
    <attribute name="new_navnumber" />
    <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    <attribute name="new_accountmanager" />
    <attribute name="accountclassificationcode" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order descending="false" attribute="name" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition value="0" attribute="statecode" operator="eq" />
      <condition value="1" attribute="new_isshareholder" operator="eq" />
      <condition attribute="accountclassificationcode" operator="in">
        <value>200001</value>
        <value>200003</value>
        <value>200005</value>
        <value>200007</value>
        <value>200009</value>
        <value>200011</value>
        <value>100000000</value>
        <value>200012</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

FetchXml is valid XML so yes you can use `xpath`

Something like `/fetch/entity/@name` should work. Views owned by Users should be ok, but be aware that there are some non-standard system views hidden away in the system

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the `returnedtypecode` attribute/field from the `userquery` entity/table. That will return the `objecttypecode` of the entity that the view queries.